# Update Event to google calendar using oauth2 and calendar Api v3 Java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

update the the event to google calendar using oauth2 and calendar Api v3. But I cant find any example.
I have insert like this And read all event

```
        Event event = new Event();
        event.setSummary("My Event");
        event.setLocation("My Event place here");

        Date startDate = new Date();
        Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
        DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
        DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));
        Event createdEvent = service.events().insert("primary", event)
                .execute();
        System.out.println("Created My Event id: " + createdEvent.getId());
```

But I have update to Event ?

Comment: look for events.patch or events.update

Comment: Could you provide docs?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update

Comment: Thanx u very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works Thanx for give link @DalmTo

```
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;

// ...

// Initialize Calendar service with valid OAuth credentials
Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
    .setApplicationName("applicationName").build();

// Retrieve the event from the API
Event event = service.events().get("primary", "eventId").execute();

// Make a change
event.setSummary("Appointment at Somewhere");

// Update the event
Event updatedEvent = service.events().update("primary", event.getId(), event).execute();

System.out.println(updatedEvent.getUpdated());
```